# Objective C allocating objects on the stack

Tags: objective-c, object, stack

I am new to Objective C and doing some practice with objects. While something like `Fraction* f = [[Fraction alloc] init ];` works, whenever I try to do `Fraction c;` I get `Interface type cannot be statically allocated` Is there anyway to allocate objects on the stack (like in c++) ? or am I trying the wrong thing ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot allocate an object statically in Objective C. There are a lot of reasons for this. Including the fact that objects should be initialized but initialization methods are allowed to change the address of the object.

In C++ a constructor must initialize the object it's called upon and cannot, in any way, change the object address. This is not true in Objective C. The equivalent of constructors (the alloc+init* sequence or a class level method) are allowed to decide that they are going to change the address of the object they are called upon (they will take care of freeing the original object, of course).

There's no way for them to free the statically allocated memory nor to change the address of your stack, of course.

Answer (score 5):

Technically, you can (see code below), but you shouldn't. Also, be it in the stack or the heap, you only have a pointer to the object, not the object itself. That is, you should write `Fraction *c`, not `Fraction c`.

```
// Allocate an Objective-C object on the stack.
// Original code By Graham Lee: 
// https://gist.github.com/iamleeg/5290797     

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <objc/runtime.h>

@interface A : NSObject
@property (assign) int meaning;
@end

@implementation A

- (id)init {
    if ([super init]) {
        _meaning = 42;
    }
    return self;
}

@end


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {

        // allocate and zero stack memory
        size_t size = class_getInstanceSize([A class]);
        id obj = (__bridge_transfer id) alloca(size);
        memset((__bridge void*)obj, 0, size);

        // set class and initialize the object
        object_setClass(obj, [A class]);
        obj = [obj init];

        NSLog(@"meaning: %d", [obj meaning]);

        // transfer ownership from ARC to CF so ARC doesn't 
        // try to improperly free the stack allocated memory
        CFTypeRef ref = (__bridge_retained CFTypeRef) obj;
    }
}
```

`alloca()` is non standard, unsafe, non portable, and prone to stack overflows.

Comment: There is a big big problem in your code. The call to `[obj init]` may try to deallocate the object and return a completely different object.

Comment: Apple discourages splitting alloc and init (`Foo *bar = [Foo alloc]; [bar init];`) because in some rare cases init may alter object allocation, for example to re-use memory of old objects (UITableViewCell maybe?). But who cares, just a crazy example allocating objects in the stack. :)

Comment: There are a lot of cases where init may reallocate the underlying memory, and even more ones where it may just free it and return something completely different. And you cannot even rely on testing as this may (and actually did) change depending on the version of the operating system and libraries.
It's not just a question of separating them. It's more that `init` assumes memory that can be freed just as much as `release` and `autorelease` do.

Comment: Note: This code is cleaner if you use MRR instead of ARC— you can skip all the `__bridge_transfer`/`__bridge` casts and the `CFTypeRef` stuff at the end.  And if you're going to do something as in-the-weeds as stack allocating Obj-C objects, you **really** should be fully comfortable with turning off ARC _(you really must be able to handle easy-mode of manual memory management before attempting the not-supported difficulty level of manual memory management )_.

Comment: Also, if you want to be really wild, you can allocate the memory for the object literally on the stack like this: `struct A_fake { char bytes[16]; }`, then in main: `assert(class_getInstanceSize(A.class) == sizeof(struct A_fake)); struct A_fake obj_storage; A *obj = (A *)&obj_storage;` and… it works as expected!  One major caveat I've found so far: Make sure you don't call `[super dealloc]` into NSObject (or any other superclass); if you want to `dealloc` the object (really deinitialization), you'll have to implement something like `- (void)deallocWithoutCallingSuper` on your class.

Comment: Final note: It looks like you can relatively safely determine if the object was allocated on the stack or via [… alloc] by checking `malloc_zone_from_ptr(obj)`.  So in the dealloc of any NSObject-inheriting class you want to stack allocate, you can make it all work by gating the super call: `if (malloc_zone_from_ptr(self) != NULL) [super dealloc];`  As before, this is pretty wild and non-standard behavior with who-knows what caveats, but [Obj-C is open source](https://github.com/apple-oss-distributions/objc4), so it's up to you.

Answer (score 1):

No, all objects are allocated on the heap in Obj-C.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot use the stack for the memory of an Objective-C object, it must be the heap (via `alloc` and `init`).

While, as pointed out by @wattson12, you can obviously store the object reference (pointer) on the stack, this still does not use the stack for the object's memory.

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting is because of a syntax error, you need to be doing:

```
Fraction *c;
```

note the missing * indicating this is a pointer to an object (you are not storing this object on the stack, you are just creating a reference to a (potential) object)

Answer (score 0):

All objective-c objects are allocated in **heap**, except for block objects. The major reason for this is:

1. pointers to an object are not tracked in Objective-C(Instead Objective-C uses a reference counting system for memory management); they can't be updated if you move the object around.
2. **stack** objects will get destroyed when the function which created them returns.

A [post](https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2010-01-15-stack-and-heap-objects-in-objective-c.html) from Mike Ash is helpful to understand this.

Answer (score 0):

A variation of @Jano's answer to use plain-C memory stack, using Obj-C MRR mode (ARC disabled, and if you're going to dare stack allocating Obj-C objects, you really should be carefully manually checking every single retain/release in your app/library):

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#include <objc/runtime.h>
#include <malloc/malloc.h>

@interface A : NSObject
@property (assign) int meaning;
@end

@implementation A

- (id)init {
    if ([super init]) {
        _meaning = 42;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    BOOL wasStackAllocated = (malloc_zone_from_ptr(self) == NULL);
    if (!wasStackAllocated)
        [super dealloc];
}

@end


struct A_storage {
    uint8 bytes[16];
};





int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        
        // allocate and zero stack memory
        assert(class_getInstanceSize(A.class) == sizeof(struct A_storage));
        struct A_storage obj_storage;
        id obj = (id)&obj_storage;
        memset(obj, 0, sizeof(struct A_storage));
        
        // set class and initialize the object
        object_setClass(obj, [A class]);
        obj = [obj init];
        
        NSLog(@"meaning: %d", [obj meaning]);
        
        // Pass `obj` to other code here, as long as you make sure those objects are
        // released and aren't holding any refs before continuing.
        
        [obj release];
        assert([obj retainCount] == 0);
    }
}
```

Caveat: This is pretty wild and unsuppported behavior with who-knows what caveats, but [Obj-C](https://github.com/apple-oss-distributions/objc4) and [Darwin's malloc](https://opensource.apple.com/source/libmalloc/libmalloc-317.40.8/src/) are open source, so it's up to you to read and understand what's going on under the hood if/when this crashes horribly in actual app/lib use.